# Does radix 1 exists?

Tags: number-theory

**Introduction**

This probably sounds a bit weird to ask, but the question is, is there such a base that is base 1.

One thing we know is that this base will contain one symbol only, but will this symbol represent *something* i.e. a value, or *nothing*?

If we try to see a connection between other bases, for instance base 10, 4, 3, 2, we see following:

- base 10 {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
- base 4  {0, 1, 2, 3}
- base 3  {0, 1, 2}
- base 2  {0, 1}

So base 1 should have the symbol $0$, in order to fit this pattern.

**Number representation**

Let's say that we introduce a new symbol, which will be used in base 1, namely *$\alpha$*. We will probably think that if we list the first numbers in base 1, we will get something like:

$$\alpha,\alpha\alpha, \alpha\alpha\alpha, \alpha\alpha\alpha\alpha$$

Which is quite logical. But, if we observe other systems, such as base 10, we will see that 10 is actually built up of two symbols. Similarly, for radix 2, $10_2$ is equal to 2, which appears to be the base.

So, would it not now be logical to claim that the definition of 1 (base 10) in base 1 is $\alpha\alpha$, or with other words, two symbols?

**Number conversion**

If we would, for example, convert $\alpha\alpha\alpha\alpha$ to radix 10, we would get following:
$$(\alpha\alpha\alpha\alpha)_1=\alpha*1^3+\alpha*1^2+\alpha*1^1 + \alpha*1^0 = (4\alpha)_{10}$$

Sure enough, $$(\alpha\alpha)_1 = 1_{10} = (2\alpha)_{10}$$
So I suppose this statement is therefore true as well:

$$(\alpha\alpha\alpha\alpha)_1=(2\alpha)_{10} + (2\alpha)_{10} = 1 + 1 = 2$$

But the interesting part here is that our symbol $\alpha$ is nothing, i.e. does not have any value at all, which implies that all numbers do not exist as values.

**Conclusion**

I do not now how correct this is, so it would be great if someone could comment upon what is written here. The question is finally, is this plausible?

Thank you,

Artem

Comment: You may wish to read the appropriate Wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_numeral_system#Comparison_with_other_systems

Comment: I was wondering how would we be able to convert a value such as $6$ in base $10$to corresponding value in base $1$? Since powers of 1 are all one, we could only write $6$ in base $10$ is =$\alpha\alpha\alpha\alpha\alpha\alpha$ - Is this so?

Comment: Note, $\alpha$ is not a value, if we would follow this pattern.

Comment: There are countless ways to represent elements of any countable set with finite repetitions of just one symbol. The base-n pattern does not extend nicely to 1 though.

Comment: How can this question be a duplicate, if it was asked 6 months before What would base 1 be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All mathematical proofs aside, common sense defines base-1 as the old "hash-mark" system, where for each item counted you make a simple mark.  While this simple mark looks suspiciously like a base-10 1, and behaves much like the 1, it pre-dates the actual 1 by many years.  This system also predates the concept of zero, so it did not have one.  Zero could be represented by a clean slate with no marks on it, but was then indistinguishable from a blank slate.  You might benefit from writing your proof without using the Arabic number system at all. (I.E. 0123456789)  The confusion in the proofs comes from the fact that base-1 CANNOT reliably represent 0, so removing it from even the implied number set is required for a proof.

Answer (score 0):

After a minute of thought I realised a tiny mistake in what I wrote before. In this answer I will prove that $\alpha = 1$, and hence show that radix one consist of only one quantity.

So, let's change our previous idea a bit, and omit zero in each finite series of a base.(please note that I am avoiding writing out zero for simplicity) Therefore,

- base 10 {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }
- base 4  {1, 2, 3}
- base 3  {1, 2}
- base 2  {1}
- base 1  { }

(considering 0 is a quantity that can be expressed in every base)

As it might be seen already, base 1 is an empty set, however, zero can still be used. In my question I defined this empty set as the symbol $\{ \}=\alpha$. Later on, I claimed that $(\alpha\alpha)_1=1_{10}$, because of my observations of other bases, where I found that $10_{10}=10;$ $ 10_2=2;$ $10_{\pi}=\pi$ (i.e. in any base, 10 is representing the value of that particular base.)

Now, it is clear that if we only are to use one symbol, $(\alpha\alpha)_1=1_{10}$. But, what if we try to construct a value of two similar symbols in any other integral base? For instance, $$11_{10}=11;$$ $$11_2=3_{10}$$
where the general trend is:
$$11_b=b+1$$
which means that the value of this number is one more than the base.
So the case for base 1 is following: $$(\alpha\alpha)_1=2_{10}$$
and by converting $$(\alpha\alpha)_1=(2\alpha)_{10}$$
and solving the equation $$2\alpha=2$$ $$\alpha =1$$

$$\therefore \{\} \to \alpha$$
From nothing, we have created something.
$\square$

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to prove here.  You said you are proving that $\alpha = 1$, but what is the definition of $\alpha$?  What does it mean to "define the empty set" as $\alpha$? And what does it mean to write $\{\} \to \alpha$?

Comment: I will need to think about a possible mistake with this assumption.  It seems that $(xx)_b = x (mod b)$ breaks the whole thing. $\therefore (\alpha\alpha)_1 = \alpha (mod 1)$, $\implies 2\alpha=\alpha (mod 1)$ $\implies 2\alpha-\lfloor 2\alpha \rfloor = \alpha$ $\therefore \alpha = 0$.  //sorry for confusing everything.

Comment: I'm afraid that I still don't understand your answer.  Also, in your last comment, it is not correct that $2\alpha = \alpha \pmod{1}$ implies $\alpha = 0$.  It is true for any integer $\alpha$.

Comment: By the way, why is it not true? $\alpha$ is an integer, so I suppose that $2\alpha$ is an integer as well, so no fractional part, hence 0?

Comment: The three dots means "therefore", right?  If $\alpha$ is, say, 1, then $2\alpha = \alpha \pmod{1}$ but $\alpha \ne 0$.  So the implication fails.